# table: change font family

Tags: tables, fonts, fontfamily

I am so used to my combo markdown pandoc latex => pdf that I am loosing my LaTeX skills. Sometimes I need in my markdown a better table layout than markdown tables are offering. So I insert it in LaTeX.

I need to change a table to a fixed font size, so that all numbers are aligned under each other;

Thank you in advance for your help

marek

ps: the tags need to revised: LaTeX and Fontfamily not allowed!

here a minimal example in tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.6,0.4,0.8}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.31,.47,.26}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,.49,.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myred}{HHHHHHHH}\\
    \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myred}{00000000}
\end{tabular}

A subnet mask of a classfull IP /24 has 1s for all \textcolor{myblue}{Network bits} and 0s for all \textcolor{myred}{Host bits}. 

If you are \textcolor{myviolet}{subnetting} a classfull net, you are borrowing bits from the \textcolor{myred}{Host part}. For example a /26 subnet mask in binary would look like follows:

\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
    \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myblue}{NNNNNNNN} & \textcolor{myviolet}{SS}\textcolor{myred}{HHHHHH}\\
    \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myblue}{11111111} & \textcolor{myviolet}{11}\textcolor{myred}{000000}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ttfamily\begin{tabular}....`

Comment: there is a [tag:fontfamily]  tag, there is no latex tag as 99.9% of questions here are about latex

Answer (score 1):

You can specify most colors and usage of `\ttfamily` in the column specifications.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}
\definecolor{myviolet}{rgb}{0.6,0.4,0.8}
\definecolor{myred}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.31,.47,.26}
\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{1,.49,.0}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ 
  *{3}{>{\color{myblue}\ttfamily}c}
  >{\color{myred}\ttfamily}c
}
  NNNNNNNN & NNNNNNNN & NNNNNNNN & HHHHHHHH\\
  11111111 & 11111111 & 11111111 & 00000000
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
A subnet mask of a classfull IP /24 has 1s for all \textcolor{myblue}{Network bits} 
and 0s for all \textcolor{myred}{Host bits}. 

If you are \textcolor{myviolet}{subnetting} a classfull net, you are borrowing 
bits from the \textcolor{myred}{Host part}. For example a /26 subnet mask in 
binary would look like follows:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{
  *{3}{>{\color{myblue}\ttfamily}c}
  >{\ttfamily}c
}
  NNNNNNNN & NNNNNNNN & NNNNNNNN & \textcolor{myviolet}{SS}\textcolor{myred}{HHHHHH}\\
  11111111 & 11111111 & 11111111 & \textcolor{myviolet}{11}\textcolor{myred}{000000}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very useful answers!